# Multivariate multiple regression with constraints on dependent variables in R

Tags: r, constraints, linear-regression, multivariate-testing

I have several dependent variables (exactly 5) and independent variables. I would like to generate a linear regression model with several dependent variables in R. I saw how to do it with `lm`:

```
rm <- lm(cbind(Y1,Y2,Y3,Y4.Y5) ~ X1 + X2 + ... + Xn, data = m)
```

However, I would also like to add a **constraint on dependent variables**: the sum of Y variables must be equal to 1 (`Y1 + Y2 + Y3 + Y4 + Y5 = 1`).

I have checked, but I have only found how to constraint independent variables.

Thank you in advance!

Pablo.